# How to share windows 8 app with clients

Tags: windows, cordova, windows-phone-8

I am making a windows 8 app for one of our clients. How can i share the app with them so that they can install it on their windows 8 phone and test it.

I tried sharing the xmp file, but when they try to install the app it says "Not a company app". I do have a windows dev company account with me, but not able to figure out how to get the app installed on my clients windows 8 phone.

Please help.

Comment: Perhaps this will be useful: [Beta testing your app and in-app products](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj215598(v=vs.105).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options to "ad-hoc" distribute your alpha/beta version:

- *Company app distribution for Windows Phone* to read more about this option visit [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206943(v=vs.105).aspx)
- You can publish the app to the Marketplace using the *Hide from users browsing or searching the Store* so it will be private, only users with a link will be able to access it
- you can use the Beta app distribution (i believe there is a limit of few thousand users using a beta version, 10000 maybe? you have to add email addresses of users manually)
- *Windows Intune for Direct Management of Windows Phone devices*. You can "distribute applications to users in either of the following ways: **External link** or **Software installer**
  Details on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn643709.aspx)